# Express js Mongoose alternative to MySQL % Wildcard

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been reading up and tried a few different code snippets that others have had success with, but I can't seem to get it to work.

What I'd like is for users to search using only part of the term i.e pe for 'peter'. I'd like to have a wildcard on the search term.

My code so far, which isn't working:

```
router.get('/:callsign', function(req,res){
var search = req.params.callsign;
var term = escape(search);
term = term.toUpperCase();
if(search=="*" || search==""){
    res.redirect("/");
}
User.find({'callsign' : new RegExp('^'+term+'$', "i") }, function(err, callsign){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log('No user found'+err);
        req.flash('message','Sorry, something went wrong. Try again.');
        res.render('callSearchResults'),{
            message: req.flash('message'), 
            title: 'Sorry, no results'
        }
    }
    if(callsign){
        console.log('Callsign:'+callsign+term);
        res.render('callSearchResults',{
            call: callsign,
            title: 'You searched for '+search,
            query: term
        });
    }else{
        console.log('No entries found'+search);
    }
});
});
```

Also, 'callsign' callback is constantly true - even when there are no results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for this search. Literal `^` mean that pattern must be at the beggining of string, and `$` that at the end. If you want just to match part you don't need to add them, so example below:

```
new RegExp(term, "i")
```

Also there is a good mechanism of full-text search build-in mongo. You can read about them from official [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/).

About queries in mongoose, when there is now object and checking in callback. The returned object is Array of documents, and in JS empty array is casted to `true` statement. Instead check lenght array, like this:

```
if(callsign.length > 0) {
  // Logic
} else {
  // Nothing found
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, I have updated my code and it is now working as intended. I shall do a bit more research on the use of RegExp.